# My app shows different icon on phone app setting

Tags: android, flutter

Apps shows different icon on phone app settings and icons are normal anywhere else I tried different icons and restart emulator but nothing happened help me please.

App on menu:

[image]

App on settings:

[image]

App on task:

[image]

Comment: There are different dpi versions of app icon files. Are they all changed?

Comment: yes all dpi icons are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, your app has an icon in both the `<application>` and `<activity>` elements in the AndroidManifest.xml. If these icons are different, you will see the `<activity>` icon on the home screen (because it starts the activity), and the `<application>` icon in the settings (because it represents the app).